# Failed to download repository information | Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, repository, downloads, dropbox

I already checked for a possible answer to my question, but, how to fix this since my details are different from the other people here. Here's my error information on Software Updater:

```
[W:Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 199.47.216.171 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 199.47.216.171 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.]
```

Any advise would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The failed repository seems to be someone's dropbox. The owner may have removed the files or there may be a routing problem. Do you know anything about a third party repository on the system? Can you tell us more about it.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Comment: @mikewhatever It looks like the official repository *for the Dropbox software* (the APT line for which looks like `deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu quantal main`), **not** like someone's personal dropbox files!

Comment: @EliahKagan: It's Dropbox's Official Private PPA, just like Google provides for Chrome. Moreover, it looks like removing the PPA and adding it again (if necessary) would solve the issue since `404 Error` is not generated when we follow the link in browser. This is certainly covered in the answers given in that question.

Comment: @Aditya No, there's a difference between an unofficial repository and a PPA. These are not PPA's. Private PPA's are still hosted on Launchpad and have `launchpad` in the URL. If the answers to that PPA-specific question aren't really PPA-specific, then the question should be generalized. That needs to happen *before* we start closing non-PPA questions as duplicates of it. Furthermore, I seem to recall that discussions geared toward generalizing it have resulted in no action because it doesn't really apply fully to non-PPA software sources. But I could be remembering wrongly.

Comment: @EliahKagan: But the answers given there would still solve the problem (maybe the script provided by FossFreedom won't work - not sure).. but other information is certainly as much applicable as for any other private hosted apt-repository or PPA hosted on launchpad.. I don't think this requires a separate question, but ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8117/discussion-between-eliah-kagan-and-aditya)

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that your computer has access to the Internet?
2. You can always download from other repositories.
3. Try `ping`ing them first prior to downloading from them.
4. Maybe try `wget` or `apt-get`?

Comment: Yep, i'm connected. But, how do I repair the error?

Comment: This page should help you: (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates)https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates.

Comment: There's a lot of topics on that page. Where should I go?

Comment: Sorry, it should be [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates) site.

Comment: And another point: you should be checking for other repositories instead of the default ones. And why are you downloading the files for two different architectures (`and64` and `i386`)? Also, Try changing your download server:
`System > Administration > Software Sources.` Change the "Download from:" dropdown box to some other server.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox's package repository doesn't provide packages specifically for Ubuntu 12.10 (`quantal`), but the packages for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (`precise`) should work fine. Open up `Software Center > Edit > Software Sources`, find the Dropbox entry on the Other Software tab, click Edit, and replace `quantal` with `precise`.