# Failed to download repository information while installing updates

Tags: apt

When i run system update then i got following error:

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64      (20130820.1)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

please help me on this.

Comment: Similar to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256229/failed-to-download-repository-information-ubuntu-12-10) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240109/why-do-i-get-failed-to-download-repository-information)

Comment: @dhpasta : i was already used both links, But i can't able to solve this question.

Comment: @Waldir Leoncio : same question.

Comment: Could you **edit** your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`